# Are download usage statistics available through the iPhone API?

Tags: iphone

You're my last hope stackoverflowers.

Comment: Are you referring to AppStore statistics?

Comment: Hey Ben, I'm referring to the cellular network stars under "general setting/usage".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that is not possible on iphone.

Answer (score 2):

No.

You need to go through the itunes connect web site for that